# Bootstrap selector for multiselect- select all option

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

So what i need is an select all option in multiple bootstrap selector as an option so i just create a select as

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" multiple>
   <option value="all">All</option>
   <option value="1">Dog</option>
   <option value="2">Cat</option>
   <option value="3">Tiger</option>
</select>
```

And when i click `All` it will remove all other options except all, and if i click any other than `All` then it need to remove all options

What i tried is like

```
$(".selectpicker").change(function(event){
    if ($( this ).find("option:first").is(':selected')) {
        $( this ).find("option").prop('selected', false);
        $( this ).find("option:first").prop('selected', true);
    } else {
        $( this ).find("option:first").prop('selected', false);
    }
});
```

But once `All` clicked then always all is activated and nothing can be clicked, i even tried to get value on `onclick` event but due to bootstrap selectpicker i can able to get it?

Any tricks to made this possible? i can do this with static variable for one selecpicker but can't able accomplish with multiple selectpicker in a form.

Comment: check my edited answer to see if it solves your issue

Answer (score 2):

**New edit**

Here is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/0z54s3wd/1/)

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
var all = $('option[value=all]');
$('.selectpicker').change(function() {
var all = $('option[value=all]'); 
var thisVal = all.html();
if (all.is(':selected')) {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselectAll');    
    $('ul.dropdown-menu > li[rel=0]').addClass('selected');
    $('span.filter-option').html(thisVal);
} else {
    $('ul.dropdown-menu > li[rel=0]').removeClass('selected');
}
});
```

Comment: i am using this http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ plugin in which option click is not wokring

Comment: it is working partially, as i mentioned in question i cant achieve this for multiple selectpicker eg http://jsfiddle.net/tktn3hgd/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like

```
$("#multiple-select option").prop("selected", "selected");
$('#multiple-select').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Must use prop.